# Does the MacOS have awareness of its charge current or charge rate?

Tags: battery, charging, power

An important function of a laptop computer is charging the battery. Does the Mac OS allow the user to know how much current is being used to charge the battery? i.e. is there a Terminal command or utility or log page in which this information is exposed?

The answer to this question may be no.  It is okay if that is the case. Also, it is not necessary the answer be in milliamps. It may be expressed as a "percent" (%) or even some other term such as "juice"(tm), "go stuff"(tm) or whatever else makes it comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, macOS does "allow" the user to know that information.

An easy way to access that information is to use the third party app coconutBattery:

https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/

It shows you "Charging with: xxx watts".

Depending on your laptop model, you can use Terminal commands such as `pmset -g batt`, `ioreg -w0 -l` and `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` to get information about your battery. You will need to search and parse the outputs of those commands for the specific information, you're looking for.

Comment: what does `pmset -g batt, ioreg -w0 -l` do?

Comment: Those two commands will give you information about your battery as described. -w0 just means that it won’t clip the output to your terminal width.